X-Files episode with a sewer monster
Please help me find this episode of the X-Files
I recall a "monster", if you will, that was able to navigate the sewer system. At one stage, a poor unlucky guy, I think maybe a construction worker, sat down on the toilet. At that stage the monster crawled up through the sewers and, well, killed him I think.
I was quite young. And this being X-Files, it scared me. So if that is enough to get the episode name and number, the help is greatly appreciated.

Hi Nicholas. Have you considered Googling the title of your question? The Flukeman from The Host pops right up.

@Walt thats the one. Thanks very much. reason i asked here was the keep some sort of "record", so i have a place to come back and get the answer.

I see. OK, I put it up, anyway. Glad you found it.

You're looking for The Host (Season 2, Episode 2), AKA the Flukeman episode.

A body is found in the sewers of New Jersey, and Agent Mulder is strangely assigned to the case. Soon, the killer seems more like an X-File-worthy creature than a homicidal man. Could his placement in this case be coincidence, or does somebody want the X-Files to continue? 

The monster is a fluke-like human who is a product of the Chernobyl disaster and he hides in toilets. The episode is a fan-favorite thanks to its creepy vibe and great make-up effects. Here's the monster (Warning: Creepy):




yes very creepy indeed. i was so scared to use toilets after watching this episode. aah how young and foolish i was
